# Usage of "make" and "become"

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Is it **always** valid to use *make* as a verb which causes a change by force in the personality/emotions/behaviors of objects?

Is it **always** valid to use *become* before all human emotions/senses/adjectives to express a change?

Is there any general rule which one to use when?

Comment: "Always" is a tough standard to reach. _Became angry, made sad, become jubilant,_ and _make excited_ all sound fine to me. But it's hard to say there are **no** exceptions hiding somewhere in the shadows. And even if there are no exceptions, that doesn't mean _make_ and _become_ would **always** be the best words to use in that context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, *make* is used in a context of "to cause something":
*You **make** me cry* — meaning, I was not crying, but because of you I start.

*Become* is simply *"to change {one's own} state"*.

Imagine Alice sees a sad Bob. Alice tells a funny joke to Bob, and he becomes happy. The following sentences are all valid:

- *Alice **made** Bob happy*;
- *Bob **became** happy*;
- *Alice **made** Bob <s>to</s> <sup>(1)</sup> **become** happy*;

So, as you see, *to make* applies to a causing subject, while *to become* applies to an object that changes.

<sup>(1)</sup> Thanks to @StoneyB; *make* takes bare infinitive, so can't use *to* here.

Answer (score 2):

"make" is a transitive verb, therefore it infers an action to the object.
On the other hand, "become" is an intransitive verb, denoting a change in state.

For example:

> "She will make the dinner."

and

> "The acorn that became the mighty oak."

Both have wide usage, but usually there are more specific verbs that can be used in place of "make" or "become". For example:

> "She will cook the dinner."

and

> "He turned into a fine young man."

Comment: Sorry, I think, it's not very accurate. Another meaning of _make_ fits better: _make=cause_, not _make=produce_.